# objective-c property name: use uppercase character as first character of property name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, syntax

It seems that the property name in Objective-c must start with lowercase letters, since the setter is written in camel case.

Is there any method to define a property (which has a setter method) start with upper case characters?

Comment: The programming convention is anyway, to start variable and method names lower-case, and types and classes upper-case. I would stay with this convention, since it makes your code more readable.

Comment: You obviously didn't bother trying it.  It works just as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@import Foundation;

@interface M : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Uppercase;

@end

@implementation M

@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    M *m = [M new];
    m.Uppercase = @"I hate conventions.";

    NSLog(@"%@", m.Uppercase);

    return 0;
}
```

The above gives the following output:

```
➜  test  ./a.out 
2016-10-23 09:58:21.291 a.out[52998:1646241] I hate conventions.
```

As you can see from the code, both the setter and getter are used the same way as any other property.

Answer (score 3):

First: Don't do it.

Second: It mostly works. However, if you have one property "Uppercase" and one property "uppercase", they will both want to create a setter named "setUppercase", so you are in trouble.

Comment: Obviously, you would just specify the `setter` name in the property declaration (e.g., `@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=setUppercase2:) NSString *Uppercase;`) to avoid this latter problem. But, of course, you're right: It would be absurd to have two properties that differ only in the capitalization of the first letter. And it's much better to just adopt [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1).